# Cat touching during prayer - can I move him without invalidating salat?

Tags: salat, animals, tashahhud, cats

I was taught as a kid to raise my finger when I'm reciting the shahadat and then stopped practicing Islam and now in my thirties trying to start practicing it again and starting to do the 5-daily namaz.

However, I am finding that my cat sees the raised finger when I'm on the ground as a perfect time to give my finger a face rub.

Based on hadith, I understand his actions (he's a male cat) don't violate the wudu or prayer but can I move him off of my prayer mat while reciting the next part or should I just let him be, ignore him and focus on prayer?

Would me reverting to wordly affairs during prayer to remove a worldly distraction while reciting the words and after having made niyat invalidate the prayer?

Comment: Speaking while praying invalidates the prayer immediately specially if you do it intentionally. otherwise, let the cat play, and you focus on praying, al Hussein and Al-Hassan used to play around the prophet and go on top of him while performing sujood and the prophet would let them play normally and he would focus on his prayer.

Comment: @user35194 you can add it as an answer with reference

Answer (score -1):

I think I've inferred an answer by relating the cat to the example of Prophet's grandchildren who played on him and got on his back when he was praying.

I should let him do what he wants without myself reacting much and especially not verbally but physical touching should be okay to move him.

I should keep praying as I have made niyat already and allow him to touch and play with me during salat without playing back with him.

Answer (score -1):

According to Islamic teachings, the presence of a cat during prayer (Salat) does not invalidate the prayer even if they pass in front of you. This is based on the principle that prayer is inherently valid, and there is no evidence to suggest that cats can invalidate it. Therefore, if a cat touches you or comes near you during prayer, it does not invalidate your Salat​​​​.

Additionally, there is no sin if cats pass in front of you while you are offering Salah, as animals are not bound by Shariah. However, it is recommended to offer Salah in a place free from interference, such as cats that may dirty the prayer mat or disturb you by crawling around​​.

Regarding the movement in prayer, minor adjustments, such as moving your limbs slightly to scratch your nose or face, or to cover your mouth while yawning or sneezing, do not invalidate the prayer. Excessive movement, however, which changes the form of the prayer or if an onlooker from afar would not recognize it as prayer, would render it invalid​​. SeekersGuidance confirms that the prayer is valid despite minor movements, as only excessive movement invalidates the prayer. It is disliked to fidget during the prayer, but slight movements necessary for the performance of the prayer are permissible​​.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

- The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “He interrupts the prayer of the woman, the donkey and the dog * as a examples 
  so if a cat touch you while praying then there is no invalidating if happened

Comment: Yeah I read that and still wasn't sure what to do.

Comment: Eslam - if I move him, or talk to him, that breaks the niyah, right?